# C# WPF while loop waiting for button click

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Want to do a while loop who will go only forward iterations after button click.
example :

```
    int buttonclick = 0;
    while (buttonclick < 30)
    {
        buttonclick++;
        Next_click;
    }
```

Next_click is the click event handler.

Comment: actually what you are trying to achieve, with this snippet

Comment: Create a global class variable of integer type. Then in the click event handler check if value of that integer is less than max number, do something and increment it. That way you won't need a `while` loop.

Comment: it would of course help us if you provided the XAML front-end used in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to run the loop in a different thread or use await. I would propose to just use a new thread. Then you add an `AutoResetEvent` to your class:

```
AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Then you replace `Next_click` with `are.WaitOne()`.
Then you create a clickHandler for your button and put this code in it:

```
are.Set();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable:

```
private int _buttonclick = 0;
```

Create event for button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

In the `Button_Click` event increment `_buttonclick` and check for `_buttonClick >= 30`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _buttonclick++;

    if(_buttonclick >= 30) {
       // code here
    }
}
```